# Is it necessary to add .row in the container-fluid block?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it necessary to add a  `.row` in the `.container-fluid` block?

On bootstrap website, it say:

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

I have been doing like this without `.row` and it work fine:

```
<div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg ">
   <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
           <table>
              ......
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to put a div with class ``row`` if you don't need to separate content in columns.

Comment: I see, I am not going to separate content in columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at a `row` class in BootStrap CSS, you'll notice there's `-15px` of margin on both the left and right. This is to compensate for the `15px` of padding a `container` provides. This is important if you're nesting columns within your row as the columns themselves have `15px` of padding (called a "gutter" in many cases).

As BootStrap say:

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That
>   padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative
>   margin on .rows.

In other words, you should use a row if you're nesting columns, if not then there's not an absolutely essential need for them...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, no need to put **useless div** with class `row` if you don't use the bootstrap grid system. And obviously you aren't here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out what .row does. In bootstrap it removes the margin from the left and right side of the div (gutter). With that knowlegde you can make out if you need to use it or not. :)

I used .row many times within the .container fluid block.